# Limit the page numbers shown in pagination

Tags: pagination

I have a pagination script that displays a list of all pages.
My site has a lot of pages, and all page numbers are shown in the pagination.
I would like to only show ten of the numbers at a time
like this:
Prev [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10] Next

How can I accomplish this? Here is my code:

```
$tableName="jobposting";        
$targetpage = "index.php";  
$limit = 6; 

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$stages = 3;
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
if($page){
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
}else{
    $start = 0; 
    }

// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

// Initial page num setup
if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
$prev = $page - 1;  
$next = $page + 1;                          
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
$LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    


$paginate = '';
if($lastpage > 1)
{   




    $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
    // Previous
    if ($page > 1){
        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>prev</a>";
    }else{
        $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>prev</span>";   }



    // Pages    
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page){
                $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
            }else{
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
    {
        // Beginning only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
            $paginate.= "...";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        // Middle hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
        {
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $paginate.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
            $paginate.= "...";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        // End only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $paginate.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
        }
    }

            // Next
    if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
    }else{
        $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
        }

    $paginate.= "</div>";
```

}
 ?>

Comment: Sorry your code is unreadable. Pagination can be done simpler, I advise you to do it from scratch and search on the web for simple example

Comment: His/her code is fine. It's not unreadable it's quite simple to understand.